# Draw and erase line

Tags: mfc

I have a mfc mdi application.

I have a black color line.

On clicking draw button I have to draw red color line over the back color line.

On clicking delete button I have to erase the red color line but the black color line should be visible.

I am able to draw red color line but I dont know how to erase red color line?

I am using below code. On erasing the line, I am getting kind of green color line and black color line also got erased.

```
void CScrRulerView::DrawLine(CDC* pDC, CRect rulerRect, bool bDraw)
{
    int nPrevMode;

    CPen pen(PS_SOLID,1,RGB(255,0,0));
    CPen* pPenOld = pDC->SelectObject (&pen);
    if(bDraw)
        nPrevMode = pDC->SetROP2(R2_COPYPEN);
    else
        nPrevMode = pDC->SetROP2(R2_NOT);
    pDC->MoveTo(rulerRect.left,rulerRect.top);
    pDC->LineTo(rulerRect.right,rulerRect.bottom);
    pDC->SelectObject(pPenOld);
    pDC->SetROP2(nPrevMode);


}
```

I am using SetROP2(R2_NOT); for erasing whether I have to use some other option?

Comment: You 'erase' a drawing by restoring the previous background. You already know how to draw a black line. Sometimes, you just have to put the Lego pieces together.

Comment: Is there any possible for  just erasing the line without restoring the previous background.

Comment: There are several ways to restore the previous image, e.g. fully rendering the previous image, or re-drawing the line to be erased using an appropriate raster operation (XOR). However, the question indicates a lack of insight as to how rendering is done in the Windows GDI. You are going to have to get comfortable with that first. Using a library (like MFC) is probably not helpful in doing so.

Comment: I tried R2_XORPEN. It is working for me.Actually I have ruler, I am displaying red color line in the ruler for indicating cursor position. On scrolling I am getting flickering.

Comment: You would have to XOR twice, with the same color to restore the initial image. Although that isn't going to produce a red line; it would be composed with the original image. There are no shortcuts here: You are going to have to restore the original image, one way or another. You could render into an offscreen device context, which would also deal with the flicker issue. But really, what you absolutely, positively need to do is learn about the basics of GDI rendering. Again, there are no shortcuts.

Comment: I drew the view as a bitmap and I am able to meet my requirement without flickering.Thanks IInspectable